# What is the fastest way to upload files to Akamai?

Tags: performance, ftp, akamai

I have an ftp directory with Akamai now and I need to upload images as fast as possible (possibly 1+ million per day)

What would be the fastest way to sync local files to an ftp site?

thanks

Comment: Will your server hold up to the load of those million + files being requested from it?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of FTP, use Rsync. It has lower overhead than FTP and is well suited to synchronising a large filebase.

[Rsync documentation](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/documentation.html)

Akamai Netstorage supports Rsync as an upload method. It may need to be enabled in the Akamai control panel - whoever administers your Netstorage user accounts can enable it.

Rsync is included in all Linux distributions, if you are on Windows you can get it as part of [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: What on Akamai are you uploading those files to. Neither the Client-side Downloads or NetSession Download Manager APIs seem like a good fit to upload your million plus images to.

Answer (score 0):

1 million a day sure is a lot, its hard to imagine what requires having such a huge number resources. All I can suggest is solving this purely at the ftp sync level, using an off the shelf tool. (Maybe http://www.ftpsynchronizer.com/?)

Failing that, knocking up a directory watching ftp uploader wouldn't be a hugely difficult programming job in most common languages that have ftp libaries.

The other alternative is that if you can get these files on an internet facing server, you can switch to using Akamai Http Content Delivery and get Akamai to pull the images rather than you having to continuously push them.

Comment: Could someone supply a link to the documentation for what you called "Akamai Http Content Delivery?" I'm not finding it specifically. In my project, I have to take a lot of files from a private SFTP server and host them on Akamai (via Onstream). It would be efficient if I could get Akamai to do the pulls for me, instead of having my dynamic site's application server pull from SFTP and push the files to Akamai.

Answer (score 0):

if you have such huge number of files and you want to upload faster, then I would suggest going for 'signiant' product which improves the upload time drastically. its a 3rd party upload service which works with Akamai very well, many customers use it.